# MASM16 Array manipulation/accessing

Tags: assembly, masm

I have an array that I want to manipulate and access but I haven't been able to figure it out even after reading through guides and tutorials.

For example I have an array called:

> array1 db 5 dup (0) ; A 5 byte array with the value of 0

How do I put a number (0-9) into each element in the array?
And how would I go about printing out the values for each element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the array:

```
mov byte ptr [array1],0  ; Store 0 in the first element
mov [array1 + 1],bl      ; Store the contents of BL in the second element
mov al,[array1 + 2]      ; Read the third element and put it in AL
```

To print a single decimal digit, assuming that you're going to run this in a DOS-compatible environment:

```
mov dl,[array1]    ; Get the first element
add dl,'0'         ; Convert from a value 0..9 to a character '0'..'9'
mov ah,2
int 21h            ; INT 21H / AH=2: WRITE CHARACTER (in DL) TO STDOUT
```